# Get error in sql script file with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a problem with on my Web Application(php and mysql).

When a new customer send Sign up Form, I have execute a SQL script DML ( create table... , insert... ) to create a Database for he.

How to is the best way to do this and get possible problems in execution?

I'm trying for this way, with a sql file with error:

```
<?php
try{
    $sql = file_get_contents( 'script.sql' );
    $st = $pdo->prepare( $sql, array(
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false
    ) );
    $st->execute();
}
catch(\Exception $e){
    ...
}
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @JayBlanchard 
The sql script is too long. I'm trying get if it exist.

    Sample:
    CREATE SCHEMA ... OK
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xxx`.`tbl_a` ...OK
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xxx`.`tbl_a` ...OPS

Comment: Have you tried breaking the SQL script into smaller parts.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Breaking the script in parts is not a good way in my opinion. Because we will lose the headers of the script : SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';